# Case insensitive and inclusive ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have views that print out a table of guides that have the word 'farming' in their titles.

```
  def farming
   t = Guide.arel_table
    @guides = Guide.where(t[:title].matches('%farming'))
  end
```

The problem is I want to show all guides that have **at least** any kind of spelling of the word 'farming' in it. So "Farming for Dummies" should show up in the search, too.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match `Farming for Dummies` you need to use `farming%`, i.e. `%` should be after the word `farming`.

Try the following to return all records with `title` including the word `farming` anywhere in `title`:

```
def farming
  t = Guide.arel_table
  @guides = Guide.where(t[:title].matches('%farming%'))
end
```